# Calculate the sum of values for each date, and return the highest sum

Tags: function, google-sheets, sum, max, google-sheets-query

I have the following theoretical fields: `Date` and `Hours Played` and three rows:

- 1st row: the Date column has the value "1/12/2016", while the Hours Played column has the value "2".
- 2nd row: the Date column has the value "1/12/2016", while the Hours Played column has the value "2".
- 3rd row: the Date column has the value "1/06/2016", while the Hours Played column has the value "3.5".

If I use the `=MAX()` function, the day with the most hours played will be 1/06/2016 with 3.5 hours. However, in reality the day with the most hours played is 1/12/2016 with 4 hours total.

Does anyone know of a function to use that would return the highest sum of the hours played for each date (in this case: `4`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function is appropriate here. If the dates are in column A and hours are in column B, it could look like

```
=query(A:B, "select sum(B) group by A order by sum(B) desc limit 1 label sum(B) ''")
```

Meaning: sum B, grouping by A, return the highest value, don't label it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Meta! Say, if I wanted to return just the date with the most hours, do you know how I would manipulate this function?

Comment: For example, in the function you gave me the returned value is "4", but how would you return the date instead (e.g., "1/12/2016")?

Comment: The easiest is to return both at the same time:  `select A, sum(B)` instead of just `select sum(B)`